# Mapbox Android SDK - Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mapbox, segmentation-fault

After updating Android Studio to version 2.1.3, I get this weird error when trying to load a Mapbox View (which worked perfectly until then, and I didn't make any changes before or after upgrading Android Studio).

The only log I got is this one:

```
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xdeadcab1 in tid 9429 ()
```

I made some research already, but I couldn't figure out why it does that, or how to handle this. Each time I launch the app, it crashes when loading this Mapbox View...

Any ideas or information about that?

EDIT:

Thank you Cammace for your comment. I will answer it here.

I'm actually using the version 4.1.1 of the SDK, and cleaning + rebuilding the project changes nothing...

I'm not sure I know exactly what stacktrace is (since I'm pretty new to Android Studio), but here is the additional lines that I got in logcat when removing all filters:

```
                                                    --------- beginning of crash
09-19 10:26:41.858 2926-3175/flow.bricks A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xdeadcab1 in tid 3175 ()
09-19 10:26:41.963 1230-1230/? I/SELinux: SELinux: Loaded file_contexts contexts from /file_contexts.
09-19 10:26:41.964 1230-1230/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
09-19 10:26:41.964 1230-1230/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'Android/sdk_google_phone_x86_64/generic_x86_64:6.0/MASTER/3079352:userdebug/test-keys'
09-19 10:26:41.964 1230-1230/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
09-19 10:26:41.964 1230-1230/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'x86_64'
09-19 10:26:41.964 1230-1230/? A/DEBUG: pid: 2926, tid: 3175, name:   >>> flow.bricks <<<
09-19 10:26:41.964 1230-1230/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xdeadcab1
09-19 10:26:41.964 1230-1230/? W/debuggerd64: type=1400 audit(0.0:8): avc: denied { search } for name="com.google.android.gms" dev="vdc" ino=114708 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
09-19 10:26:41.964 1230-1230/? W/debuggerd64: type=1400 audit(0.0:9): avc: denied { search } for name="flow.bricks" dev="vdc" ino=115477 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
09-19 10:26:41.964 1230-1230/? W/debuggerd64: type=1400 audit(0.0:10): avc: denied { search } for name="flow.bricks" dev="vdc" ino=115477 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
09-19 10:26:41.964 1230-1230/? W/debuggerd64: type=1400 audit(0.0:11): avc: denied { search } for name="flow.bricks" dev="vdc" ino=115477 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
09-19 10:26:41.964 1230-1230/? W/debuggerd64: type=1400 audit(0.0:12): avc: denied { search } for name="flow.bricks" dev="vdc" ino=115477 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
09-19 10:26:41.964 1230-1230/? W/debuggerd64: type=1400 audit(0.0:13): avc: denied { search } for name="flow.bricks" dev="vdc" ino=115477 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
09-19 10:26:41.964 1230-1230/? W/debuggerd64: type=1400 audit(0.0:14): avc: denied { search } for name="flow.bricks" dev="vdc" ino=115477 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
09-19 10:26:41.964 1230-1230/? W/debuggerd64: type=1400 audit(0.0:15): avc: denied { search } for name="flow.bricks" dev="vdc" ino=115477 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
09-19 10:26:41.964 1230-1230/? W/debuggerd64: type=1400 audit(0.0:16): avc: denied { search } for name="flow.bricks" dev="vdc" ino=115477 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
09-19 10:26:41.964 1230-1230/? W/debuggerd64: type=1400 audit(0.0:17): avc: denied { search } for name="flow.bricks" dev="vdc" ino=115477 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
09-19 10:26:41.964 1230-1230/? W/debuggerd64: type=1400 audit(0.0:18): avc: denied { search } for name="flow.bricks" dev="vdc" ino=115477 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
09-19 10:26:41.964 1230-1230/? W/debuggerd64: type=1400 audit(0.0:19): avc: denied { search } for name="flow.bricks" dev="vdc" ino=115477 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
09-19 10:26:41.964 1230-1230/? W/debuggerd64: type=1400 audit(0.0:20): avc: denied { search } for name="flow.bricks" dev="vdc" ino=115477 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
09-19 10:26:41.964 1230-1230/? W/debuggerd64: type=1400 audit(0.0:21): avc: denied { search } for name="flow.bricks" dev="vdc" ino=115477 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
09-19 10:26:41.964 1230-1230/? W/debuggerd64: type=1400 audit(0.0:22): avc: denied { search } for name="flow.bricks" dev="vdc" ino=115477 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
09-19 10:26:41.964 1230-1230/? W/debuggerd64: type=1400 audit(0.0:23): avc: denied { search } for name="flow.bricks" dev="vdc" ino=115477 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
09-19 10:26:41.964 1230-1230/? W/debuggerd64: type=1400 audit(0.0:24): avc: denied { search } for name="flow.bricks" dev="vdc" ino=115477 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
09-19 10:26:41.964 1230-1230/? W/debuggerd64: type=1400 audit(0.0:25): avc: denied { search } for name="flow.bricks" dev="vdc" ino=115477 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
09-19 10:26:41.964 1230-1230/? W/debuggerd64: type=1400 audit(0.0:26): avc: denied { search } for name="flow.bricks" dev="vdc" ino=115477 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
09-19 10:26:41.964 1230-1230/? W/debuggerd64: type=1400 audit(0.0:27): avc: denied { search } for name="flow.bricks" dev="vdc" ino=115477 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
09-19 10:26:41.964 1230-1230/? W/debuggerd64: type=1400 audit(0.0:28): avc: denied { search } for name="flow.bricks" dev="vdc" ino=115477 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
09-19 10:26:41.964 1230-1230/? W/debuggerd64: type=1400 audit(0.0:29): avc: denied { search } for name="flow.bricks" dev="vdc" ino=115477 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
09-19 10:26:41.964 1230-1230/? W/debuggerd64: type=1400 audit(0.0:30): avc: denied { search } for name="flow.bricks" dev="vdc" ino=115477 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
09-19 10:26:41.964 1230-1230/? W/debuggerd64: type=1400 audit(0.0:31): avc: denied { search } for name="flow.bricks" dev="vdc" ino=115477 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
09-19 10:26:41.964 1230-1230/? W/debuggerd64: type=1400 audit(0.0:32): avc: denied { search } for name="flow.bricks" dev="vdc" ino=115477 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
09-19 10:26:41.964 1230-1230/? W/debuggerd64: type=1400 audit(0.0:33): avc: denied { search } for name="flow.bricks" dev="vdc" ino=115477 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
09-19 10:26:41.964 1230-1230/? W/debuggerd64: type=1400 audit(0.0:34): avc: denied { search } for name="flow.bricks" dev="vdc" ino=115477 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
09-19 10:26:41.964 1230-1230/? W/debuggerd64: type=1400 audit(0.0:35): avc: denied { search } for name="flow.bricks" dev="vdc" ino=115477 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
09-19 10:26:41.964 1230-1230/? W/debuggerd64: type=1400 audit(0.0:36): avc: denied { search } for name="flow.bricks" dev="vdc" ino=115477 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
09-19 10:26:41.964 1230-1230/? W/debuggerd64: type=1400 audit(0.0:37): avc: denied { search } for name="flow.bricks" dev="vdc" ino=115477 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
09-19 10:26:41.964 1230-1230/? W/debuggerd64: type=1400 audit(0.0:38): avc: denied { search } for name="flow.bricks" dev="vdc" ino=115477 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
09-19 10:26:41.964 1230-1230/? W/debuggerd64: type=1400 audit(0.0:39): avc: denied { search } for name="flow.bricks" dev="vdc" ino=115477 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
09-19 10:26:41.964 1230-1230/? W/debuggerd64: type=1400 audit(0.0:40): avc: denied { search } for name="flow.bricks" dev="vdc" ino=115477 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
09-19 10:26:41.964 1230-1230/? W/debuggerd64: type=1400 audit(0.0:41): avc: denied { search } for name="flow.bricks" dev="vdc" ino=115477 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
09-19 10:26:41.964 1230-1230/? W/debuggerd64: type=1400 audit(0.0:42): avc: denied { search } for name="flow.bricks" dev="vdc" ino=115477 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
09-19 10:26:42.137 1230-1230/? A/DEBUG:     rax 00000000deadcab1  rbx 00007fe0222894c0  rcx 0000000000000000  rdx 00007fe022289460
09-19 10:26:42.137 1230-1230/? A/DEBUG:     rsi 0000000000000000  rdi 00007fe021d49b60
09-19 10:26:42.137 1230-1230/? A/DEBUG:     r8  0000000000000006  r9  00007fe043086299  r10 00007fe04309d4cc  r11 00007fe042fa9000
09-19 10:26:42.137 1230-1230/? A/DEBUG:     r12 00007fe021af7268  r13 00007fe0430aaa00  r14 00007fe02c1c1000  r15 000000000000002e
09-19 10:26:42.137 1230-1230/? A/DEBUG:     cs  0000000000000033  ss  000000000000002b
09-19 10:26:42.137 1230-1230/? A/DEBUG:     rip 00007fe021d49b6d  rbp 00007fe021af70c0  rsp 00007fe021af70c0  eflags 0000000000010206
09-19 10:26:42.141 1230-1230/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
09-19 10:26:42.141 1230-1230/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 0000000000251b6d  /data/app/flow.bricks-2/lib/x86_64/libmapbox-gl.so
09-19 10:26:42.141 1230-1230/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 0000000000251b97  /data/app/flow.bricks-2/lib/x86_64/libmapbox-gl.so
09-19 10:26:42.141 1230-1230/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 0000000000251b56  /data/app/flow.bricks-2/lib/x86_64/libmapbox-gl.so (std::terminate()+22)
09-19 10:26:42.141 1230-1230/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 0000000000250851  /data/app/flow.bricks-2/lib/x86_64/libmapbox-gl.so
09-19 10:26:42.141 1230-1230/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 000000000025011f  /data/app/flow.bricks-2/lib/x86_64/libmapbox-gl.so
09-19 10:26:42.141 1230-1230/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 00000000002500b1  /data/app/flow.bricks-2/lib/x86_64/libmapbox-gl.so
09-19 10:26:42.141 1230-1230/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 00000000001358ec  /data/app/flow.bricks-2/lib/x86_64/libmapbox-gl.so (mbgl::OfflineDatabase::ensureSchema()+300)
09-19 10:26:42.141 1230-1230/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 000000000013570c  /data/app/flow.bricks-2/lib/x86_64/libmapbox-gl.so (mbgl::OfflineDatabase::OfflineDatabase(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned long)+204)
09-19 10:26:42.141 1230-1230/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 000000000012a7de  /data/app/flow.bricks-2/lib/x86_64/libmapbox-gl.so (void mbgl::util::Thread<mbgl::DefaultFileSource::Impl>::run<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned long&>, 0ul, 1ul>(std::__1::tuple<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned long&>&&, std::__1::integer_sequence<unsigned long, 0ul, 1ul>)+94)
09-19 10:26:42.141 1230-1230/? A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 000000000012a73c  /data/app/flow.bricks-2/lib/x86_64/libmapbox-gl.so (std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<mbgl::util::Thread<mbgl::DefaultFileSource::Impl>::Thread<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned long&>(mbgl::util::ThreadContext const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&&&, unsigned long&&&)::'lambda'()> >(void*, void*)+124)
09-19 10:26:42.141 1230-1230/? A/DEBUG:     #10 pc 0000000000084eee  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+46)
09-19 10:26:42.141 1230-1230/? A/DEBUG:     #11 pc 00000000000296eb  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+11)
09-19 10:26:42.141 1230-1230/? A/DEBUG:     #12 pc 000000000001ce55  /system/lib64/libc.so (__bionic_clone+53)
09-19 10:26:42.218 1230-1230/? A/DEBUG: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_04
09-19 10:26:42.218 1230-1230/? E/DEBUG: AM write failed: Broken pipe
09-19 10:26:42.219 1561-1580/system_process I/BootReceiver: Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_04 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
09-19 10:26:42.231 1561-3180/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity flow.bricks/.MainActivity
09-19 10:26:42.237 1561-3180/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity flow.bricks/.FirstActivity
09-19 10:26:42.250 1203-1609/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
09-19 10:26:42.253 1561-3189/system_process D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
```

I hope it can be of any help for you... Please tell me if I'm wrong here.

I don't have any specific code snippet to provide, I just figured out that is was crashing when trying to inflate the layer containing the Mapbox View:

```
// Inflate the layout resource file
    View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResId, container, false);
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What version of the SDK are you using? The latest is `4.1.1`. Could you also provide additional information, any code snippets, and the full stacktrace (turn all filters off in logcat). Also try cleaning the project and rebuilding, I've been using 2.1.3 with Mapbox for awhile now with no troubles.

Comment: Try turning off instant run

Answer (score 0):

Can you check to make sure you have all the [mapview lifecycles](https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/#lifecycle_methods) added inside your activity. These would include:

```
onCreate();
onResume();
onPause();
onSaveInstanceState();
onLowMemory();
onDestroy();
```

[Here's an example](https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/examples/) you can work off of to make sure you have everything setup correctly. If this doesn't resolve the issue, I'll need to see more code to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: I think that's why I don't understand this problem, and I probably should have told you first: I already downloaded this example, and I've got the same error... I checked, and yes I have all this methods inside my activity.

Comment: Which version of Android are you using on the test device or are you using an emulator? You might be hitting [this issue](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/6317).

Comment: Currently I'm using the build-in emulator in Android Studio, with API 23 (Marshmallow). I cannot test it on a real device right now. Is it possible that this issue occurs only on an emulator?

Comment: Yes, this might be an issue with the emulator. We recommend using physical devices for testing. One thing you can try would be to change the Emulated Performance setting to Hardware (or software).

Comment: Alright, so I will try to test it soon on a real device and tell you if that changes anything (switching Emulated Performance did not fix it). One question though: if this is an emulator problem, will it be fixed with future updates of Android Studio or Mapbox SDK?